# Returning everything - that is DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Qt table which I am retrieving information from a database, but there is some duplicates in the database which is fine, but I want to return only the distinct values, how can I change the following SQL query to use the `DISTINCT` Keyword? The Distinct value should be the title in the following schema.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

The schema is as follows:

```
Table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
            name TEXT, 
            pdate TEXT, 
            ptime TEXT,
            title TEXT, 
            link TEXT,
```

**Edit**

I have tried a couple of things, all of which have failed. This includes selecting just the titles, etc.

Comment: Which distinct columns do you want to retrieve? all of them?  Distinct names and titles? or ones where all values are unique?

Comment: It will be the title column as this is where the duplicates *could exist

Comment: So you want a list of all unique titles?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 yeah exactly :)

Comment: And when there are multiple rows with the same title, from which one should the other columns' values come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this to get all unique names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM Table
```